# Unable to show search result on page by using jquery ajax and codeigniter pagination

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to show dynamic search result on search page where I'm using jquery ajax for getting data from codeigniter pagination library but everything is working fine even when I check ajax response in developer tools I can see the result but unable to show on page. Following are the code that I used:

> **search_page.php - (view file)**

```
<?php include("includes/header.php");?>

<!-- Search Result Will Be Show Here -->
<div class="row" id="search_result_section"></div>

<!-- Search Result Pagination Will Be Show Here -->
<div id="search_result_section_pagination_link"></div>

<?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
```

> **jQuery Ajax (Placed in Footer - footer.php - view file)**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   <?php if($this->uri->segment(1) === 'search'): ?>
    // Search Query

     load_search_page_data(1);

     function load_search_page_data(page)
     {
             var q = $('#search').val();
             if(q == '')
             {
                 q = '';
             }
             $.ajax({
                     url:"<?php echo base_url('search/result/'); ?>"+page,
                     method:"POST",
                     dataType:"JSON",
                     data:{q:q},
                     success:function(data)
                     {
                       console.log(data);
                       $('#search_result_section').html(data.search_result_section);
         
    $('#search_result_section_pagination_link').html(data.search_result_section_pagination_link);
                     }
             });
     }


     $(document).on('click', '.pagination li a', function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             var page = $(this).data('ci-pagination-page');
             load_search_page_data(1);
     });
     // Search Query
     <?php endif; ?>
  });
```

> **Search.php (controller file)**

```
 class Search extends CI_Controller
    {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Crud', 'crud');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

    public function index($page = null)
    {

      $data['page'] = 'search';
      $data['seo_title_data'] = 'Search Result | '.$this->crud->getSetting('default_seo_title');;
      $data['seo_description_data'] = $this->crud->getSetting('default_seo_description');
      $data['seo_keywords_data'] = $this->crud->getSetting('default_seo_keywords');
      $data['seo_canonical_data'] = base_url('search.html');

      $data['q'] = $this->input->post('q');

      $this->load->view('theme/search_page', $data);

    }

    public function getSearchData()
    {
      sleep(1);
      $q = filter_var($this->input->post('q'), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      $config = array();
      $config['base_url'] = '#';
      $config['total_rows'] = $this->crud->get_search_count($q);
      $config['per_page'] = 3;
      $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
      $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
      $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="product-pagination"><ul class="pagination">';
      $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
      $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
      $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
      $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
      $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
      $config['next_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>';
      $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
      $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
      $config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>';
      $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
      $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
      $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='active'><a href='#'>";
      $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
      $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
      $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
      $config['num_links'] = 2;
      $this->pagination->initialize($config);
      $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $start = ($page - 1) * $config['per_page'];
      $output = array(
       'search_result_section_pagination_link'  => $this->pagination->create_links(),
       'search_result_section'   => $this->crud->search($q, $config["per_page"], $start)
      );
      // echo '<pre>';
      // print_r($output);
      echo json_encode($output);
    }

  }
```

> **Crud.php (model file)**

```
// Get Product Count
 public function get_search_count($q)
 {
   $qarray = explode(' ', $q);

   $this->db->distinct();
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('products');
   $this->db->like('product_name', $q, 'both');
   if (count($qarray) > 1) {
     foreach ($qarray as $s) {
       $this->db->or_like('product_seo_title', $s, 'both');
       $this->db->or_like('product_seo_description', $s, 'both');
       $this->db->or_like('product_seo_keyword', $s, 'both');
     }
   } else {
     $this->db->or_like('product_seo_title', $q, 'both');
     $this->db->or_like('product_seo_description', $q, 'both');
     $this->db->or_like('product_seo_keyword', $q, 'both');
   }
   $query = $this->db->get();
   echo $query->num_rows();
 }

// Get searched product data
 public function search($q, $limit = null, $start = null)
 {
   $output = '';

   $qarray = explode(' ', $q);

   $this->db->distinct();
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('products');
   $this->db->like('product_name', $q, 'both');
   if (count($qarray) > 1) {
     foreach ($qarray as $s) {
       $this->db->or_like('product_seo_title', $s, 'both');
       $this->db->or_like('product_seo_description', $s, 'both');
       $this->db->or_like('product_seo_keyword', $s, 'both');
     }
   } else {
     $this->db->or_like('product_seo_title', $q, 'both');
     $this->db->or_like('product_seo_description', $q, 'both');
     $this->db->or_like('product_seo_keyword', $q, 'both');
   }

   if($limit != null && $start != null)
   {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
   }

   $query = $this->db->get();
   // return $query->result();
   foreach ($query->result() as $product) {
     $output .= '<!--Single Product Strat-->
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-md-4 product__box__container my-3">
                      <div class="single-product mb-40">
                        <div class="single-product">
                          <div class="product-img">
                            <a href="'.$product->product_vanity_url.'.html">
                            <img src="'.$product->product_img_one.'" alt="'.$product->product_name.'">
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-action">
                              <ul>
                                <li>
                                  <a href="'.base_url($product->product_vanity_url).'.html" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add To Cart"  class="add_cart" data-productid="'.$product->product_uid.'">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="product-content">
                            <h4><a href="'.base_url($product->product_vanity_url).'.html">'.$product->product_name.'</a></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="product-price">
                            <span class="price">₹ '.number_format($product->product_price, 2).'</span>
                            <span class="regular-price">₹ '.number_format($product->product_price_mrp, 2).'</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Single Product End-->'.PHP_EOL;
                  }
    return $output;
 }
```

> **routes.php (routes file)**

```
$route['search'] = 'Search';
$route['search/result/(:any)'] = 'Search/getSearchData/$1';
```

Comment: Can you show output of `data` ?

Comment: you can find here ..... https://infipick.com/shop/search.html

Comment: Hi i check that , ajax request is made when page gets load  but didn't find any `console.log(data);`  because i think on load your search box doesn't have any value . Also , you are submiting your form as i see your search box is under form tag ?